# How to change font in column header in Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid that I want to change the font in column header. The code is,

```
<% Html.Kendo().Grid<FlightCenterWeb.Models.SalesViewModel>()
.Name("Sales")
.TableHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:9pt;" })
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:400px" })
...
.Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Bound(a => a.SalesId)
.HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-size:12pt;" })
.Width(50);
...
}).Render();
%>
```

But it does not work. I need help on this. Thanks.

Comment: I have checked your code and it works perfectly. Check if you do not have applied some font-size !important css properties for 'a' or 'th' element.

Comment: After change the css for h1 - h6, I solve the problem even without HeaderHtmlAttributes. Does the fonts in Kendo grid have something to do with the h1 -h6? Any thought?

Comment: No, there is no any 'h' tags in kendo grid unless you are using it in any template (header, row, footer etc.)